# How can we disable a tenant and reject all connection below this tenant?

Tags: kaa

We want to disable a tenant and reject all connection below this tenant.
We try to set the application's credentials as "Internal".
The new endpoint seems can't connect to Kaa server, but the endpoint ever connect to Kaa seems still connect to Kaa server successfully.
We also try to delete the application record in "application" table in Mysql, but the result still the same.
Have any suggestion to disable a tenant??
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. The attribute credentials responsible for how endpoint authenticate itself. Also, you can delete applications through Admin UI as admin of tenant. This way is much convenient comparing with removing records directly from database.

To accomplish your goal you need to delete each EP from each application in your tenant thus KAA server close all active sessions with EPs.